# What toolkit can I use to convert PDF (forms) into TEX forms?

Tags: pdf, latex, ms-word

I have some forms that were created with Acrobat, they are fillable PDF files (they contain named fields).  Is there a toolkit that will reformat them into TEX/LaTEX files and leave all the fields intact?  With Acrobat, I can export the forms to Word format (haven't tried it yet), so that might be another path I can take as well.  So maybe Word -> TEX would be acceptable.

I know the two beasts are not identical, the fields in a TEX file are just def's at the top of the file, but I'd like to get some of the benefits of TEX (fields that need to grow and expand to cover multiple pages) without having to re-author the forms that have already been created in acrobat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way to convert from PDF back to TeX. PDF is more or less a terminal format. Your best bet is to preserve the content structure from the PDF, and re-implement them in TeX. I've had a crack at making fill-able forms from TeX, but it didn't go well.

You're traveling down a difficult road.

If you have acrobat at your disposal, I would use whatever functionality it provides.